# Values of $a$ for which range of $y=\frac{x+1}{a+x^2}$ contains the interval [0,1]?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

> **Question**: For what values of $a$ does the range of $y=\frac{x+1}{a+x^2}$ contain the interval [0,1]?

This is how I did it:
Cross multiplying and making the discriminant of the quadratic in $x$ to be greater than zero.
$$4ay^2-4y-1\le0$$ 
For this to be defined, $a\ge-1$
I solved further and got that $a\in(-1,\frac54]$ [$-1$ is not included since for $a=-1$, $y\ne0$]

However, the correct answer is $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,\frac54]$, which seems to totally contradict my solution since $a\not\lt-1$.
What did I do wrong and what would be a better way to solve the question?

Comment: I think the interval might be $(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\frac54]$, check it out.

Comment: @Alpha Please see the edited question.

Comment: I still didn't understood that how you took value of $x$ to be greater than zero. I mean it can belong between $(-1,\infty)$, as if the value of $x$ in negative fraction will also lead to the value of $y$ to be between $[0,1]$. Don't you think?

Comment: @Alpha I'm sorry for the typo. The $x$ and the $\ge0$ are separate; the discriminant is $\ge0$.

Comment: [This graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281%2Bx%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%2F2%29) shows $a=\frac 12$ works fine.

Comment: @ross I included it in my solution...

Comment: True, but it is not in the "correct answer" you quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless $a=-1$, we will have $y=0$ if $x=-1$.  We need to have $y=1$ for some $x$ and not have a zero of the denominator in the middle.  So we get $1=\frac {x+1}{a+x^2}, a+x^2=1+x, x^2-x+a-1=0, x=\frac 12 \pm \frac 12\sqrt{5-4a}$  We clearly need $a \le \frac 54$.  If $a \lt -1$  we are fine.  We find $x=\frac 12(1-\sqrt{5-4a})$ yields $y=1$ and we get there from $x=-1$ before we hit the pole.  For $-1 \lt a \le \frac 54$ we take the plus sign in the expression for $x$ and it works fine.  So $a \in (-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,\frac 54]$

Answer (score 3):

You need $f(y) = 4ay^2-4y-1$ to be non-positive. 
To be more precise, you need it to be non-positive for all $y$ in the range
$0 \le y \le 1$.

For $a \ne 0$, this function of $y$ has an extremum
at $\frac{1}{2a}$, and the value at that extremum is 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right) = -1 - \frac{1}{a}.$$

For negative values of $a$, this extremum is a maximum. Moreover, if $a < -1$,
then $\frac{1}{a} > -1$ and therefore $f\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right) < 0$.
Since this is the maximum value of $f$, then whenever $a < -1$
you have $f(y) < 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$,
which is more than you needed. 
Hence whenever $a < -1$, the range of $y=\frac{x+1}{a+x^2}$ contains the interval $[0,1]$.

For any $a$ such that
$-1 <= a <= 1$, clearly $4ay^2 <= 4y$ whenever $0 \le y \le 1$, so $f(y) < 0$.
But the value $a = -1$ is ruled out for reasons you already know.

For $a > 1$, the minimum of $f$ occurs at $f\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)$, 
and $\frac{1}{2a} < \frac{1}{2}$, so if $f(1) \le 0$ then $f(y) \le 0$ 
for all $y$ in the range $0 \le y \le 1$.
(And of course if $f(1) > 0$ then $1$ is not in the range of $y=\frac{x+1}{a+x^2}$.)
In other words, $a$ must satisfy the condition 
$f(1) = 4a - 5 \le 0$.
Therefore $a \le \frac{5}{4}$.

Combining these three cases, $a$ must be somewhere in the set 
$(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,\frac{5}{4}]$.

I notice that $f(y)$ has no zeros when $a < -1$. But the important thing is that it is
non-positive; it does not need to actually attain the value zero.

Comment: Damn, I made such a foolish mistake. Thanks.