# For what real values of $a$ does the range of $f(x)$ contains the interval $[0,1]$?

Tags: functions, quadratics

**Question** :

For what real values of $a$ does the range of $f(x) = \cfrac{x+1}{a+x^2} $ contains the interval $[0,1]$?

My doubt lies in the further preceding of this question.

The book states :

> Let $y = \cfrac{x+1}{a+x^2} $ . Which implies - $$yx^2 - x + (ay-1) = 0$$ 
>   has real roots for every $\color{blue}{y \in [0,1] }$.

I'm not sure how it concluded that it is real for the given interval of y.

I'm also known to the fact that : $D \ge 0$ for the quadratic to have real roots.

And here, $ D = 1 - 4y(ay-1) \ge 0$

Not sure how to go on from here.

Comment: Actually it turns out this is a duplicate questions.  See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848552/values-of-a-for-which-range-of-y-fracx1ax2-contains-the-interval-0?rq=1.  Fortunately our results are in agreement!

Comment: Yep, I was already aware about that duplicate question, even before posting my own question. But, my doubt wasn't answered there so decided to put it separately. Thanks to you and others for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks easier to consider the reciprocal $$y = g(x) = \frac{a+x^2}{x+1} = x-1 + \frac {a+1}{x+1}$$ and look for the values $a$ so that the range of $g$ contains $[1, \infty).$

we will break the problem in into three cases: $a > -1, a = -1$ and $ a < -1.$

consider the case $a > -1.$  here we have the graph of $y = g,$  hyperbola with a local min  $$ y = 2\sqrt{a+1} - 1 \text{ at } x = -1 + \sqrt{a+1}.$$
for the local min to be less than or equal to $1,$ it is necessary that $$-1 < a \le 0.\tag 1$$

case $a = -1$
 we have $g = x-1.$  the range of $g$ certainly contains $[1, \infty)$

in case $a < -1,$ the range of $a$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$ which contains $[1, \infty)$

we can conclude that the constraint on $a$ is $$ a \le 0 \implies range\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2 + a}\right) \subseteq[0,1]. $$

Comment: what if $a=0, 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Here what I have come up, but you better analyze deeply !!!
$$0\leq \frac{x+1}{a+x^2}\leq 1$$

You may have three possibilities which depend on $x$:

If $x<-1$ then $a\leq -x^2+x+1$.

If $x=-1$ then $(a<-1\lor a>-1)$, i.e., $a\neq -1$.

If $x>-1$ then $a\geq -x^2+x+1$.

I think that you cannot exactly specify the value of $a$ without $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Up front I will say that I did not leverage the suggestions from your book.  But here is what my analysis yields regarding values for $a$.

When $a=-1$ the rational function $y$ reduces to $\frac{1}{x-1}$ which never takes on the value of zero. So one immediate restriction is $a \ne -1$.

Assuming the above restriction, set $y=1$ and solve for $x$ which gives:
$$x = \frac {1 \pm \sqrt{5-4a}}{2}.$$

In order for $y$ to ever achieve a value of $1$ we then need $a \le 5/4$.  In fact values of $a$ that exceed this bound will yield values of $y$ that will always be less than $1$.

When $0 < a \le 5/4$ the function smoothly passes through the range $[0, 1]$ without any drama.

At $a=0$ we pick up a single positive verticle asymptote at $x=0$ yet the function will still pass through the desired range as $x$ approaches $0$ from below.

When $-1<a<0$ there will be a pair of vertical asymptotes and yet the function will only pass through the range $[0, 1]$ as $x$ approaches $-\sqrt {|a|}$ from below.

When $a < -1$ the function will pass through the range $(-\infty, \infty)$ and hence the range of interest when $x$ falls in $(-\sqrt {|a|}, \sqrt {|a|})$.

So it appears that the function will pass through the range $[0, 1]$ when $a \le 5/4$ and $a \ne -1$.